# What version of Logic Pro X works on macOS Sierra?

Tags: macos, compatibility, logic

I noticed that the latest version of Logic Pro X requires macOS 10.13.6 (High Sierra) or newer. Does anyone know what the last version of Logic Pro X that can run on macOS 10.12.6 (Sierra) is?

Comment: If you're running Sierra, you should only be able to download the last version that works on that OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 10.4.4

Sources: [1](https://www.logicprohelp.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=144530), [2](https://www.soundonsound.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=66718), [3](https://cdm.link/2019/06/logic-pro-x-10-4-5-upgrade/), [4](https://www.gearslutz.com/board/apple-logic-pro/1245348-10-4-4-released.html). Current is 10.4.8.